# AWS S3 bucket policy: permissions based on account id prefix

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a centralized CloudTrail bucket which contains the CloudTrail logs of multiple accounts. Is it possible to write a bucket policy which allows that account `123456789112` can only download logs from `Awslogs/123456789112` and that account `456789012345`can only download logs from `Awslogs/456789012345`etc ? I don't want to hardcode this for each account since I have a lot of accounts. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

AWS IAM policies (and bucket policies) support a few [policy variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_variables.html) that you can use as dynamic values such as `aws:SourceIp`, however account ID is not one of them. There is a [`aws:userid`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_variables.html#principaltable) variable but it's the account ID only for the root user, for other principals like IAM user/role it is the user/role name. Technically if you used the AWS root user to access this bucket, you could use the `userid` variable in the `Resource` element to achieve what you want but it is strongly recommended not to use the root user for such everyday tasks ([AWS recommendation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id.html#id_root)).

There are also policy condition keys like [`aws:PrincipalAccount`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html#condition-keys-principalaccount) but without a relevant policy variable these cannot be used to dynamically compare the requesting account ID with the resource. There are no other IAM feature that could be used to achieve this.

I don't know your exact environment but a few things to consider:

- I'd recommend to explicitly list the allowed principal ARNs anyway because even if you have many accounts, you should allow only specific IAM users/roles to read the bucket to follow the least privilege principle. Granting access based on account ID would allow all users/roles in that account to read these files and not just specific services. (unless this is the objective)
- since this is a cross-account access (principal in account `A` wants to read from the bucket located in account `B`), you will need to allow this access on both sides, both in the requester's IAM policy and the target bucket's policy. Just a heads up. [More info on AWS.](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cross-account-access-s3/)
- I would consider using Terraform to simplify the management of these resources

Hope this helps, let me know if you have more questions!